# Read a value from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

Im new to JSON and php. I need to grab the **lat** and **lng** from the following json after calling json_decode(). But I don't know how to access them.

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "1600",
      "short_name": "1600",
      "types": [ "street_number" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Mountain View",
      "short_name": "Mountain View",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "California",
      "short_name": "CA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "94043",
      "short_name": "94043",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 37.4219720,
        "lng": -122.0841430
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 37.4188244,
          "lng": -122.0872906
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 37.4251196,
          "lng": -122.0809954
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, JSON objects decode to objects, and arrays to arrays:

```
$data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat
$data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng
```